# Flink Filter Stream based on another Stream Deterministically

Tags: java, stream, apache-flink

I have 2 DataStreams in Flink (with common timestamps and from Kafka) with one of them containing some signal values and the other containing the activeness (simple active-inactive) information. I have tried `RichCoProcessFunction` with a simple state `private  ValueState<Boolean> seen;` and the results are non-deterministic. If I run on the same set of data (with same timestamps) by using `startFromEarliest` I sometimes get different values filtered. How can I make it deterministic? I'm sharing my `KeyedCoProcessFunction` skeleton below.

```
private ValueState < Boolean > seen;

@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    ValueStateDescriptor < Boolean > descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor < > (
        // state name
        "have-seen-key",
        // type information of state
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint < Boolean > () {}));
    seen = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
}

@Override
public void processElement1(SomeEvent < Double > value, Context ctx, Collector < SomeEvent < Double >> out) throws Exception {
    if (seen.value() == Boolean.TRUE) {
        out.collect(value);
    }
}

@Override
public void processElement2(SomeEvent < Double > value, Context ctx, Collector < SomeEvent < Double >> out) throws Exception {
    if (value.value == 1) {
        seen.update(Boolean.TRUE);

    } else {
        seen.update(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing an event time join of the sort you want can be done as a `RichCoProcessFunction`, but it can be a bit complex. You might prefer to implement this as a [join with a temporal table function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table-function).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's not deterministic is that the two sources are producing elements with a different pace. The simplest way to make it more deterministic is to use EventTime. This means that You would need to have timestamps assigned both to control records and the data records. Flink will then emit watermarks for Your elements.

Then You could simply buffer and wait with emitting or discarding the elements until You receive Watermark for the control stream, meaning that nothing is going change in control stream.

Without timestamps, it's virtually impossible to introduce deterministic behavior in such case, because You won't be ever able to exactly tell when the given record has arrived and which records should be dropped and which should be emitted.

Comment: Regarding the event time I agree but I might have some missing points. I've set the `TimeCharacteristic.EventTime`  and used the event time assigner but I'm still having a non-deterministic result. What modifications would my KeyedCoProcessFunction need?

Comment: As I said in the post You need to mimic the behavior that TemporalTable has, i.e. you need to wait with emitting any results or discarding them until the Watermark arrives. Then You can remove/emit results with timestamp lower than Watermark. Alternatively as described by @David in his answer You could use the TemporalTable.